# Pandas dataframe Cartesian join

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, and I would like to combine each second dataframe row with each first dataframe row like this:

First:

```
val1 val2
1    2
0    0
2    1
```

Second:

```
l1 l2
a    a
b    c
```

Result (expected result size = len(first) * len(second)):

```
val1 val2 l1 l2
1    2    a    a
1    2    b    c
0    0    a    a
0    0    b    c
2    1    a    a
2    1    b    b
```

They have no same index.

Regards,
Secau

Answer (score 8):

Create a surrogate key to do a cartesian join between them...

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0, 2],
                    'B': [2, 0, 1],
                    'tmp': 1})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'l1': ['a', 'b'],
                    'l2': ['a', 'c'],
                    'tmp': 1})

print pd.merge(df1, df2, on='tmp', how='outer')
```

Result:

```
   A  B  tmp l1 l2 
0  1  2    1  a  a 
1  1  2    1  b  c 
2  0  0    1  a  a 
3  0  0    1  b  c 
4  2  1    1  a  a 
5  2  1    1  b  c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution:

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'val1': [1,0,2], 'val2': [2,0,1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'l1': ['a', 'b'], 'l2': ['a', 'c'])
df_list = []

for x in df1.index:
    series = df1.iloc[x, :]
    series_list = [series for _ in range(len(df2.index))]
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(series_list, index=range(len(df2.index)))
    df_list.append(pd.concat((temp_df, df2), axis=1, join='inner'))

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Which produces:

```
final_df
   val1  val2 l1 l2
0     1     2  a  a
1     1     2  b  c
0     0     0  a  a
1     0     0  b  c
0     2     1  a  a
1     2     1  b  c
```